# how to find number of rows and columns of 2D array to store prime numbers between 0 to 1000

Tags: java, arrays

> Take a range of 0 - 1000 Numbers and find the Prime numbers in that range. Store the prime numbers in a 2D Array, the first dimension represents the range 0-100, 100-200, and so on. While the second dimension represents the prime numbers in that range...

To store in 2d array we need to know number of rows and columns ..can someone help me?...Integer [] is returned by the method findPrimNumbers...but i have to store the prime numbers in a 2d integer array.
This is the code I wrote.

```
 public class PrimeNmbers2D 
       {
        public static boolean isPrime(int number)
        {
            boolean status=true;
            for(int n=0;n<=number;n++)
            {
                int count=0;
                for(int i=1;i<=number;i++)
                {
                    if(n%i==0)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if(count==2)
                {
                    status=true;

                }

            }
            return status;
        }
        public static Integer[] findPrimeNumbers(int start,int end)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> primes=new ArrayList<>();
            for(int from=start;from<=end;from++) 
            {
                if(isPrime(from))
                {
                    primes.add(from);
                }

            }
            return primes.toArray( new Integer[primes.size()]);
        }
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          int[][] primeGroups=new int[10][];
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
          {
              int start=0;
              int end=100;
              for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
              {
                  primeGroups[i][j]=findPrimeNumbers(start, end);

              }
              start=end+1;
              end=end+100;
          }

      }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What problems are you facing? "can someone help me?" - yes if you speficy your problem.

Comment: If I might give you some advice, your code is unnecessary complex, simplify it. E.g. the variable names don't say anything. If you call your number just `num` then you won't remember what the number is for. You also have a list called `intArr` and an array `intArray` (which is which?). All I want to say is, don't abbreviate (except index variables like `i, j, k`) and choose the names wisely. One more thing, when you call a method `isSomething` then one expects a boolean (is it or is it not?) and not a list. Sorry I can't help.I am sure you will find the solution quickly (Lists are a good idea)

Comment: @Amongalen  my question is that i have to find prime numbers between 0 to 1000 and store all the prime numbers in a 2d array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the answer of Rafael Strack, I think I get the idea now.

So you need to find all primes from `0` to `1000`. Then group them in primes from `0-100`, `101-200`, `201-300` ....

Which means your result is an array of arrays of integers.

```
int[][] primeGroups;   // please excuse the name...
```

Now you have to initialise the first dimension:

```
int[][] primeGroups = new int[10][];
```

That is because there are 10 groups:

```
0 ->    0 - 100
1 ->  101 - 200
2 ->  201 - 300
3 ->  301 - 400 
4 ->  401 - 500 
5 ->  501 - 600 
6 ->  601 - 700 
7 ->  701 - 800
8 ->  801 - 900 
9 ->  901 -1000
```

However your `primeGroups` is still "empty". So with the solution from Rafael Strack you can implement your `isPrimeNum(int number)` and test:

```
findPrimeNumbers(int from, int to){
   ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();  // arrays don't grow dynamically, so you need a list and convert it in the end to an array
   for( ; from<to; from++){
        if(isPrimeNum(from)){
           primes.add(from);
        }
   }
   // at this point you have all your prime numbers from "from" to "to" in the primes list
   // now convert it and return it:
   return primes.toArray(new Integer[primes.size()]);   // ugly but it does the job
}
```

And finally you need to iterate over your `primeGroups` array and fill it with all the possible primeNumbers you find:

```
primeGroups[0] = findPrimeNumbers(0,100);
...
```

and so on.

**EDIT**
There are still a few "hick-ups" in your code. Here some suggestions:

**1** the name of your `isPrime(number)` method suggests, that you want to know if `number` is a `prime`. However you are iterating over all numbers from `n=0` to `n=number` and test all numbers for being primes. Remove the outer loop and it leaves you something like:

```
int count=0;
for(int i=1; i<=number; i++){
  ...
} 
return count==2;        // shortcut: no need to return true or false - just return the result of your condition
```

**2** Now to your initial question: You have an `Integer`-List and you want an `int` array, so loop:

```
int[] result = new int[primes.size()];
for(int i=0;i<primes.size();i++){
    result[i] = primes.get(i);
}
return result;
```

**3** That leaves you with two more problems in your `main` method:

```
int start=0;
int end = 100;
```

need to be outside the loop. otherwise you re-initialise them on every iteration (which will result in 10 times the same numbers)

and finally, your `findPrimeNumbers(start, end)` already returns an `int[]`. So you can simply put that result in `primeGroups[i]`

You can read it like this:

```
int[][] primeGroups = new int[10][];  // array of int arrays primegroups is a new array and can contain 10 arrays
primeGroups[i] = findPrimeNumbers(start, end);  // primeGroups at index i is the result of findPrimeNumbers... (which is an array)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: ,your answer is quite useful to me .thanks for help,but to store the prime numbers in 2 dimensional array...we need to know number of rows and columns right?.you have initialized only first dimension..what about the second dimension...i will be thankful..if u can explain this

Comment: findPrimeNumbers(0,100);   //returns us Integer array but we need it as int array

Answer (score 1):

I think your method isPrimeNum() should return a boolean, and if the return is true, you add you variable num to the array that should be returned. 
Another thing is that this part of your code is unnecessary.

```
ArrayList <Integer>intArr=isPrimeNum(num);
Object [] obj = intArr.toArray();
Integer[] intArray = (Integer[])obj;
```

you could use the code below:

```
Integer[] myArray = intArr.toArray(new Integer[intArr.size()]);
```

But i didn't understand the purpose of your code fully, if you need all prime numbers from 0 to 1000, why would you need an input? you should have a method that populate an array with all numbers from 0 to 1000, then another method that iterates through that array and puts the prime number in another array that will be returned, let's call that method findPrimeNumbers(). the method findPrimeNumbers should receive the array with all numbers and call the isPrimeNum() method to each number and add to the return Array if is true.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: With your `findPrimeNumbers()` you won't even need the array with all numbers between 0 and 1000. You could add two parameters: `findPrimeNumbers(int from, int to)` and then create a for-loop: `for( ; from<to; from++)` and then if `isPrimeNum(from)` you add it to the list.

Comment: @Rafael Strack,your answer is very helpful to me .Thanks for helping

Comment: The approach that GameDroids suggested was better! @drug you don't need to know the exactly size of the second dimension, it is like a matrix,  you can have all rows of the same size or they can have different sizes. 
To use GameDroids' example:
int[][] primeGroups = new int[10][];

primeGroups[0] = new int[10];

primeGroups[1] = new int[5];

Comment: @RafaelStrack yeah...i have done that but...findPrimeNumber(); ....returns Integer array but..we need int array...to do that again we need to create an int array and store elements in it from Integer array....which will be same as the code i posted at first....correct me if im wrong

Comment: @drug ah, now i think i got it! you want to convert the ArrayList of Integer to an array of int? you can do it like this:
ArrayList<Integer>  primes = findPrimeNumbers(0,100);
 int[] arr = primes.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();

Comment: @drug this solution above only works if you're using a java 8 or higher version. in case you're using java 7 or lower version, you would need to do a foreach on the list and add each element to the array, a lot of code but works the same way.

Comment: @RafaelStrack thanks for the help,my question is not exactly what you are thinking...i have to store prime numbers in an 2d array...im posting the code ..i have done so far...please do check it...hope u will understand my question looking at it